# How to decrypt a string in PL/SQL that is encrypted using PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, plsql

I am new to encryption and decryption techniques. I have a requirement to decrypt the response in PL/SQL received from the PHP server. The encryption method is AES128 CBC.

**PHP Code**

```
$clear_text = "Secret Message";
$str        = "0962774221568619";
$key        = "0962774221568619";

$iv = str_pad($iv, 16, "\0");
$encrypt_text = openssl_encrypt($clear_text, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$data = base64_encode($encrypt_text);

echo $data;
```

The encrypted string from the above code is: **87UMyOAog3rlmzorneakjA==**

Now I want to decrypt this string in PL/SQL. Before decrypting, first I tried to encrypt the same message by replicating PHP code in PL/SQL as below.

Encryption using PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
   input_string       VARCHAR2 (200) :=  'Secret Message';
   output_string      VARCHAR2 (200);
   encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores encrypted binary text
   decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores decrypted binary text
   encrypted_string   VARCHAR2(1000);        
   num_key_bytes      NUMBER := 128/8;        -- key length 256 bits (32 bytes)
   key_bytes_raw      RAW (32);               -- stores 256-bit encryption key
   encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type
                            DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

   iv_raw             RAW (16);

BEGIN
   key_bytes_raw := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('0962774221568619',  'UTF8');
   iv_raw        := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('0962774221568619',  'UTF8');
   
   encrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT
      (
         src => UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW (input_string,  'UTF8'),
         typ => encryption_type,
         key => key_bytes_raw,
         iv  => iv_raw
      );

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('encrypted_raw: ' || encrypted_raw);    
    
    encrypted_string:= utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_ENCODE(encrypted_raw));
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('encrypted_string: ' || encrypted_string);
END;
```

**Output**

**encrypted_raw:** 0C36016A23FE45D8C62C50615336E5C6

**encrypted_string:** DDYBaiP+RdjGLFBhUzblxg=

Here I got different encrypted strings from PHP and PL/SQL. I am not sure but seems like the PHP code replication in PL/SQL is not correct to me.

Using the below code, I am able to decrypt the string encrypted from PL/SQL.

```
DECLARE
   output_string      VARCHAR2 (200);
   encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores encrypted binary text
   decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores decrypted binary text
   num_key_bytes      NUMBER := 128/8;        -- key length 256 bits (32 bytes)
   key_bytes_raw      RAW (32);               -- stores 256-bit encryption key
   encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type
                            DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

   iv_raw             RAW (16);

BEGIN
   encrypted_raw := '0C36016A23FE45D8C62C50615336E5C6'; 
   key_bytes_raw := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('0962774221568619',  'UTF8');
   iv_raw        := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('0962774221568619',  'UTF8');
   
     decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
      (
         src => encrypted_raw,
         typ => encryption_type,
         key => key_bytes_raw,
         iv  => iv_raw
      );

   output_string := UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (decrypted_raw, 'AL32UTF8');

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Decrypted string: ' || output_string);
END;
```

**Output:** Secret Message

This is fine but I am facing challenges while decrypting the string encrypted from PHP.

**Update**

I forgot to assign a value of IV in the PHP code that I used to encrypt the string. Thanks to @topaco and @BartoszOlchowik for pointing out this mistake.

Updated code

**PHP**

```
$clear_text = "Secret Message";
$iv         = "0962774221568619";
$key        = "0962774221568619";

$iv = str_pad($iv, 16, "\0");
$encrypt_text = openssl_encrypt($clear_text, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$data = base64_encode($encrypt_text);

echo $data;
```

**Encrypted String:** DDYBaiP+RdjGLFBhUzblxg==

**PL/SQL**

```
DECLARE
   encrypted_string   VARCHAR2(1000):= 'DDYBaiP+RdjGLFBhUzblxg=='; -- Encrypted string from php
   output_string      VARCHAR2 (200);
   encrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores encrypted binary text
   decrypted_raw      RAW (2000);             -- stores decrypted binary text
          
   num_key_bytes      NUMBER := 128/8;        -- key length 256 bits (32 bytes)
   key_bytes_raw      RAW (32);               -- stores 256-bit encryption key
   encryption_type    PLS_INTEGER :=          -- total encryption type
                            DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC
                          + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;

   iv_raw             RAW (16);

BEGIN
   key_bytes_raw := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('0962774221568619',  'UTF8');
   iv_raw        := UTL_I18N.STRING_TO_RAW ('0962774221568619',  'UTF8');
    
   --convert base64 encrypted string from php to raw
   encrypted_raw:= UTL_ENCODE.BASE64_DECODE(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(encrypted_string));
   
   decrypted_raw := DBMS_CRYPTO.DECRYPT
                    ( src => encrypted_raw,
                      typ => encryption_type,
                      key => key_bytes_raw,
                      iv  => iv_raw );
                      
   output_string := UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR (decrypted_raw, 'AL32UTF8');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Decrypted string: ' || output_string);    
END;
```

**Output:** Decrypted string: Secret Message

Comment: what value is in $iv ? I got undeclared an undeclared error.

Comment: Both codes use different IVs and therefore produce different ciphertexts: The PHP code uses a zero IV (16 times 0x00), the PL/SQL code uses the key as IV. Both are insecure btw (the secure way is to use a random IV for each encryption, passed together with the ciphertext, usually concatenated).

Comment: @Topaco: if he uses different IV then its EOT.

Comment: Yeah I copied the PHP code provided by the client and in that, I missed to assign value for $IV and because of that, it is giving different cyphertexts. For testing purposes, I am using the same key and IV value but in prod, we have a different value for both. Thank you for pointing out this mistake.

Comment: New PHP code is:
`$clear_text = "Secret Message";
$iv = "0962774221568619";
$key = "0962774221568619";

$iv = str_pad($iv, 16, "\0");
$encrypt_text = openssl_encrypt($clear_text, "AES-128-CBC", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$data = base64_encode($encrypt_text);

echo $data;`

Comment: @RutvikPrajapati updating your question by changing the code is better than putting code in comment which look ugly. Remember, you can always Edit your question. When i will be home i will put that in my Oracle 19c instance and gonna try this out if the error persists. Just give me a sign if you still face that problem, or it is solved already ?

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik  I agree with you.  After commenting here, I updated the question and added the updated code for both PHP and PL/SQL. Using static key value (string value as I used in this example) I am able to solve this issue. But do you know how to use the key file (.key extension) in DBMS_CRYPTO function to decrypt this ciphertext?

Comment: @RutvikPrajapati just store the key  file as blob in the database and convert to byte raw ;)

Comment: @BartoszOlchowik Thank you. I am able to decrypt the string using key file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare same cryptographic data to be able to decrypt it correctly.

In your PLSQL code `IV` variable has different value from `IV` declared in PHP, so you wont be able to decrypt data in PLSQL, which you encrypted with different `IV` in PHP.

Using the same `IV` value in PLSQL as in PHP will solve the problem.